# Can't stop VBScript in batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to stop a certain music file from playing in the background so I can start playing another one but I can't find a solution to this. Here's the code I'm using:

```
set "file=airraid.wav"
( echo Set sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 21
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /B cscript //nologo sound.vbs
```

Comment: Press Ctrl+Break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop music by killing `cscript` process using the command `Taskkil`

Here is an example to test with :

```bat
@echo off
Title Playing Music in the background and change it
Set "URL_Music1=http://streaming.radio.funradio.fr/fun-1-44-128"
Set "URL_Music2=https://stream.initialradio.fr:8443/djbuzz-192k.mp3"
Rem :: Here we start cscript minimized to play music with URL as argument
Call :Play "%URL_Music1%"
Tracert.exe www.codereview.stackexchange.com
Call :StopMusic
::Rem We play another music
Call :Play "%URL_Music2%"
Tracert.exe www.google.com
Call :StopMusic
Pause & Exit
::**************************************************************
:Play
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo        wscript.sleep 100
echo    loop
echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
echo End Sub
)>"%Temp%\%~n0.vbs"
Start "Play Music" /Min cscript.exe //nologo "%Temp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::**************************************************************
:StopMusic
Taskkill /F /IM "cscript.exe">nul 2>&1
Exit /b 
::**************************************************************
```

Comment: @PioReds 
How does accepting an answer work?
Welcome on Stack Overflow.
Please take Stack Overflow (SO) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to say thanks on SO by accepting an answer on being helpful by clicking on gray check mark symbol left to an answer.
See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)
A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.